# Why is this attached property not updating?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, attached-properties

Alright, so I was originally just going to post this as an issue of why the binding was not working. However, as soon as I tried to minimise the code to post on SO it created yet another issue.

So, essentially, the `Extensions` class is meant to hook onto the `ListBox` and make a bindable version of `SelectedItems`. This feature of grabbing the `SelectedItems` and placing them in the `Selected` attached property works in my program (in my real program it does not seem to bind?), but not in this minimised version. I have no clue why however, the code seems to do all it needs to do.

The code I used to test it:

`.xaml.cs`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public IList Selected { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Selected = new List<object>();
            Why.ItemsSource = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        }
        private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Selected.Cast<object>().Aggregate("", (s, info) => $"{s}{info}, ").TrimEnd(',', ' '));
            MessageBox.Show(Extensions.GetSelected(Why).Cast<object>().Aggregate("", (s, o) => $"{s}{o}, ").TrimEnd(',', ' '));
        }
    }
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Selected", typeof(IList), typeof(Extensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList), HookSelectionChanged));

        private static void HookSelectionChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
            if (lb == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("This property currently only supports DependencyObjects inheriting from Selector.", nameof(sender));
            lb.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
        }

        private static void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
            => SetSelected((ListBox)sender, ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList());

        public static void SetSelected(DependencyObject element, IList value) => element.SetValue(SelectedProperty, value);

        public static IList GetSelected(DependencyObject element) => (IList)element.GetValue(SelectedProperty);
    }
}
```

`.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="My title." Height="350" Width="425" MaxHeight="350" MaxWidth="425" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="425">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox lcl:Extensions.Selected="{Binding Selected}" x:Name="Why" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
        <Button Click="Click" Content="blah"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Any ideas would be excellent! Thanks :)

Comment: This may help: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/ That PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel thing is a lifesaver for me every day (whoops, missed your DataContext binding)

Comment: Shouldn't `{Binding Selected}` be `{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}` ?

Comment: @Quantic is right -- you can also use [ `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557295(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `PropertyMetadata`, which lets you pass in `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`, which saves your consumers the trouble of having to remember to add `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: @Quantic After only using controls I did not realise that not all `Bindings` defaulted to TwoWay. Using that + implementing INotifyPropertyChanged fixed it in my test case and real program, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so all it was was me missing two things:

- I didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my test
- I did not know that `Binding`s did not default to `TwoWay` all of the time.

So all that needed to be done was this:

`.xaml.cs`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IList _selected;

        public IList Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _selected)) return;
                _selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Selected = new List<object>();
            Why.ItemsSource = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        }
        private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Selected.Cast<object>().Aggregate("", (s, info) => $"{s}{info}, ").TrimEnd(',', ' '));
            MessageBox.Show(Extensions.GetSelected(Why).Cast<object>().Aggregate("", (s, o) => $"{s}{o}, ").TrimEnd(',', ' '));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public class Extensions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Selected", typeof(IList), typeof(Extensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IList), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, HookSelectionChanged));

        private static void HookSelectionChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
            if (lb == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("This property currently only supports DependencyObjects inheriting from Selector.", nameof(sender));
            lb.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
        }

        private static void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
            => SetSelected((ListBox)sender, ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList());

        public static void SetSelected(DependencyObject element, IList value) => element.SetValue(SelectedProperty, value);

        public static IList GetSelected(DependencyObject element) => (IList)element.GetValue(SelectedProperty);
    }
}
```

and it worked brilliantly.